# Can I install GDI+ using only commands?

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying to install GDI+ in my windows docker container. I was wondering if it is possible to do this via commands in the dockerfile. I need GDI+ for a method that converts bytes to an image object: specifically the System.Drawing.Image.FromStream() method.

I'm using the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 base image for my docker container. I realize that I can use the servercore image instead, however that base image is much larger than the nanoserver one. I'd be able to save a lot of space if I could install GDI+ on this nanoserver image.

Comment: I'm surprised there's still a version of Windows available that doesn't have GDI+ preinstalled.  Never heard of nanoserver before.

Comment: Honestly I don't hink it's possible, my best bet would be trying to move away from System.Drawing and instead use SkiaSharp